# Social classification data for the UK

Tags: data-request, metadata, geospatial, geocoding

Is anyone aware of 'social classification' data sources used, for example, here:

- http://www.checkmyarea.com/EC3N4AB.htm "Wealthy singles in small city flats and suburban terraces"
- http://www.checkmyarea.com/B66HE.htm "Ethnically mixed young families and singles in terraced housing"
- http://www.checkmyarea.com/EH12NG.htm "Suburban scottish households in small terraces and flats"

Comment: Usually, such data is collected from national census, household surveys, and commercial sources.

Comment: As of 2021 June, the website referenced in this question seems to no longer be active.

Answer (score 1):

The specific classifications you refer to sound very much like [MOSAIC data from Experian](https://www.experian.co.uk/business/marketing/segmentation-targeting/mosaic/). We use this in Local Government and the classifications sound exactly like that. It's a commercial dataset though and it doesn't look like there are any free or open versions. Looks like that website uses a variety of sources but I would take a bet that MOSAIC is one of the primary ones.

Answer (score 1):

The data on this site uses the sum of AB and C1 from the census 2011 social classification data.

It can be downloaded without charge from [NOMISWEB (ONS)](https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/query/select/getdatasetbytheme.asp?theme=26&subgrp=2011%20Census%20-%20Local%20Characteristics). I think the particular dataset you are after is `LC6124EW` (LC = Local characteristics; EW= England/Wales). You should also find the same dataset for Scotland suffixed `SC` instead.

More info on the details of the classification can be found [here](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20160105160709/http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/about-ons/business-transparency/freedom-of-information/previous-foi-requests/people--population-and-community/determining-social-grade-from-census/index.html)